# How to give a constant left margin to all the views?

Tags: android, view

I have multiple horizontal linear layouts. Whithin each of these layouts which are listed vertically, I have a TextView followed by an EditText. I want to give a constant left margin to all the EditText views only so that they get aligned, how can I accomplish that? Here is the partial code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pNameL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="Segoe ui"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            style="@style/editText_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think ,Using relativeLayout will be better option

Comment: Probably, but I want to do it in this way now... I think I have to stay with this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a style in res/values/style.xml file. If style.xml is not present then create a new one.

```
<style name="editText_style">
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">30dp</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout files (in which you want to change margin) under `<EditText>` tag, apply this style using :

```
style="@style/editText_style"
```

**EDIT :** In case, where your parent is horizontal oriented, you cannot apply margin relative to your parent.
Try using `layout:weight` property. For example, if you want that your EditText starts at half of its parent and you have total 2 view in your parent including EditText then set `layout:weight` of both views to, let's say, 0.5. This gives both of the views equalspace in their parent. 
This will work only if all the `LinearLayouts`, where you want to make change, contains equal no. of views. If for different `LinearLayout` contains different no. of views then you cannot use style or there is no way to make change from single place.

**Note :** Using `layout:weight` property you cannot obtain static margin value. It is dependent on your parent size and it may vary on different screen sizes.

Comment: Yes you are right, but the problem is I want to give a constant margin to all the EditText with respect to the parent layout, however this way of doing it gives a left margin wtr to TextView preceding the EditText.

Comment: @user2254838 Margin is always with respect to its parent view. You may be doing something wrong. Please post your code so that I can look into it.

Comment: I have just edited my initial post to give a partial code. Now the EditText after the TextView gets a margin of 30dp but wtr TextView

Comment: @user2254838 Ok. Here your EditText's parent has `horizontal` orientation. In this case, it is not possible to apply margin relative to parent. You can use `layout:weight` property. See my edit.